# How to stop MMS text messages from sending

Tags: sms

I have sent a message to the wrong person and want to stop it from sending.

I quickly put the phone into airplane mode,as you do to stop normal text messages, however because this message was so large, it converted into an MMS message (which I'm guessing means it uses the Internet to send rather than a phone signal.

Putting the phone into airplane mode has stopped the message from sending, however the sending icon is still appearing next to the message, which I'm guessing means it'll send once I take the phone back out of airplane mode.

Is there a way to permanently stop the message from sending? I have also tried removing the battery and pressing force stop on the messages app in application manager